# What are the physical state invariants of loop quantum gravity?

Tags: quantum-gravity, observables, invariants, loop-quantum-gravity

What are the "physical state" invariants for [Loop Quantum Gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_quantum_gravity)?

The Wikipedia page talks about "physical states" being invariant, diffeomorphism invariance, "quantities defined on the constraint surface" being invariant, "space rotational invariance", and "knot invariance" as well as gauge invariance.

Are the physical states invariant "models" like Gauge, Gauss, knot, diffeomorphism, etc?  Or are the physical invariants like rotation, time, and mass?  If so, what are they?

Comment: It is an open question even what the "physical states" (btw the technical term is Dirac observables) of the classical General Relativity are. LQG doesn't attempt to answer this question, instead it uses partial observables on the kinematical Hilbert space to describe physical experiments, and the physical inner product (which is essentially the inner product of projections of kinematical states on the physical Hilbert space) to encode its predictions.